# looping over a list/arry: for item in list vs for item in range (0, len(list)) both showing different output

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I am writing a small function in a class in two different ways.
I expected the same behaviour of these 2 snippets of codes, however the first one throws an error and the second one runs.

Can someone explain to me why the dirst one does not work ?

Code: 1

```
class Solution:
    def firstElementKTime(self,  a, n, k):
        # code here
        countDict = {}
        for i in a:
            if (a[i] in countDict):
                countDict[a[i]] = countDict[a[i]] + 1
            else:
                countDict[a[i]] = 1
        for i in a:
            if countDict[a[i]] == k:
                return a[i]
        return -1
```

Throws the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/91ded90adaf6c5d579e2dbec3cedff79.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/91ded90adaf6c5d579e2dbec3cedff79.py", line 34, in main
    print(ob.firstElementKTime(a, n, k))
  File "/home/91ded90adaf6c5d579e2dbec3cedff79.py", line 9, in firstElementKTime
    if (a[i] in countDict):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Whereas Code 2 here :

```
class Solution:
    def firstElementKTime(self,  a, n, k):
        countDict = {}
        for i in range(0, len(a)):
            if a[i] in countDict:
                countDict[a[i]] = countDict[a[i]] + 1
            else:
                countDict[a[i]] = 1
            i = i + 1
        for i in a:
            if countDict[a[i]] == k:
                return a[i]
        return -1
```

Runs well.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is running on a’s elements, and not on the indexes.
So a[i] is like a[a[0]] in the first iteration.

for i in a

Will give you a[0], a[1], …